# Combining data in Excel from different rows to make a complete record

Tags: excel, vba

I have an **Excel** file which has a *key identifier* in one row and the associated data in another row.

**I need to combine the data in order to create meaningful reports.**

Below is an example of the data and what I'd ultimately like it to look like in the end.

Current Data Format:

- Row 1: Bob Smith
- Row 2: Data about Bob that is not needed
- Row 3: Bob's Totals (e.g. Data about Bob that is needed)
- Row 4: -blank
- Row 5: Jane Doe
- Row 6: Data about Jane that is not needed
- Row 7: Data about Jane that is not needed
- Row 8: Jane's Totals (e.g. needed data)

And this is how I need the end product to look something like this with the name and totals row only on each line:

- Row 1:  Bob Smith & Bob's Totals
- Row 2:  Jane Doe & Jane's Totals

Comment: Kindly clarify the following: in the individual's name, is there an identifier of sorts, ie. `Name:`, `Employee Name:`, etc.? In the individual's totals, is there also an identifier of sorts? This will make things easier if you can provide them.

Comment: Sorry, a picture is worth a thousands words and I'm unable to post one.  Prior to the person's name it actually reads"Agent: Bob Smith" all in the same field for that row.  The "totals" row reads "Totals" followed by cells of data that are related to Bob.  The spreadsheet is approximately 400 rows long with information for different people.  In the end I want one row for each person with their data (e.g. results for the month).  Does that make sense?

Comment: That's more than enough. I was hoping for keywords, as this is important. I hope you're comfortable with VBA because this might get a bit complicated. :) Will create mock data now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume "Bob Smith" is in A1 and "Bob's Totals" is in A3.

If you need the combined data in and one cell (Lets say A10) then

```
Private Sub abc()

Worksheets("Nameofyoursheet").Range("A10").Value = Worksheets("Nameofyoursheet").Range("A1").Value & " " & Worksheets("Nameofyoursheet").Range("A3").Value

End Sub
```

Similarly you can go on to do the same for "Jane" & "Jane's Totals"

You can modify the `& " " &` part of the code to include any text you like to come in between, for instance `& " the totals are" &`

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is pretty rudimentary and straightforward. The logic is as follows:

- Copy the sheet to a new sheet called `Dummy` to be safe.
- Delete all unwanted rows. We leave everything with `Agent` or `Totals` (which was why I was asking for keywords).
- Iterate over the new rows and just copy and paste the total rows to the cell beside the name.

**Set-up:**

[image]

**After first two steps:**

[image]

**After whole code is finished:**

[image]

Code is as follows:

```
Sub WeirdConsolidate()

    Dim SourceSh As Worksheet, DummySh As Worksheet
    Dim DummyLastRow As Long, NewLastRow As Long
    Dim Iter As Long, Iter2 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set SourceSh = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        SourceSh.Copy After:=.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Set DummySh = ActiveSheet
    End With

    With DummySh

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        .Name = "Dummy"
        DummyLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Iter = DummyLastRow To 1 Step -1
            If InStr(1, .Range("A" & Iter).Value, "Totals") = 0 And _
                InStr(1, .Range("A" & Iter).Value, "Agent") = 0 Then
                .Rows(Iter).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next Iter

        NewLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Iter2 = 2 To NewLastRow
            .Range("B" & Iter2 & ":D" & Iter2).Copy .Range("B" & (Iter2 - 1))
            .Rows(Iter2).EntireRow.Delete
        Next Iter2

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Modify parameters accordingly. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: This looks perfect.  Thanks so much for your help and quick response!